# Highcharts multiple series force xAxis start point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to have multiple optically synchronized charts. There is no problem with single series chart. But If I mix column and area chart, it starts to behave strangely.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container1',
        height: 200,
    },
  xAxis: {
    startOnTick: false,
    minPadding:0,
    ordinal: false,
    crosshair: true,
    endOnTick: false,
    min:1532767826000,
    max:1532789426000,
    type: 'datetime',

  },
    series: [{
        type: 'area',
        name: 'Serie1',
        data: [ [1532767826000, 0],[1532789426000, 0] ]

    },
    {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Serie1',
        data: [ [1532767826000, 0],[1532789426000, 0] ]

    }]
});
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/fpnayfuq/49/

I'm not able to force area chart to have same x-axis start point as the other single series charts.

Answer (score 0):

If you force all series to have the same [**pointPlacement**](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.pointPlacement), it should work:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    pointPlacement: 'on'
  }
},
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/fpnayfuq/58/